# Firebase Dynamic links always returned CANCELED

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using dynamic links for my app.

I've followed the tutorial step-by-step and I'm able to open the app by clicking on the link posted on facebook.

But when I invoke getInvitation, I always have CANCELED as status of AppInviteInvitationResult.

```
    AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, false).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        // Extract deep link from Intent
                        Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                        String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);

                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    } else {
                        Log.d("StartActivity", "getInvitation: no deep link found.");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Into debug, I can see that result.getStatus() returns CANCELED, but the click on lick open the app correctly.

Where I'm wrong?

EDIT: The link that I'm using is:
https://wft4z.app.goo.gl/?link=https://aqld.it/testlink/112972&al=aqld://test/about?params%3D17363&apn=com.project.mydeeplink

The filter on manifest:

Comment: How does your url look like (opened, full size url)? If you added that to your question I would be easier to analyze what could be wrong. Also, when/where do you invoke get invitation?

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: apn is twice in your url, I wonder if that has any effect? I should have asked for intent-filter also, but if your app package is com.project.deeplink and the data in your intent filter in the manifest looks something like this: <data android:scheme="aqld" android:host="test" android:pathPattern=".*" /> they should be fine. If the intent filter differs seriously, that is likely a problem.

Comment: I've tried without success. I've changed my question with more infos.

Answer (score 0):

The status is canceled when no intent has been received. I was wondering the same thing and it turned out that my links created in firebase web page were wrong. I wrote some ideas on how to debug the url problem as an answer to another question. If you have the same problem as I did, they should be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37615175/4025606

Comment: could you please show the initialization of mGoogleApiClient. Have you added AppInvite.API?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't directly answer your question but you could eliminate badly formed urls as a root cause by using this page to create firebase dynamic links for both ios and Android: http://fdl-links.appspot.com/

Comment: I've tried, doesn't works. I'm trying with an app that isn't on Play Store, this could be the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. The app starts after opening the link but the callback gets always canceled. However my app is on the playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Just double-check if you have added the SHA-1 in the firebase console and the added SHA-1 matches the SHA1 of the generated APK. I was seeing the same issue - result.getStatus() returning CANCELED prior to this, but after adding the SHA-1 on firebase console, it started working fine. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've verified and the SHA1 are added correctly.