# Redirect issue with Firebase Dynamic Link Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, firebase, hyperlink, firebase-dynamic-links

I Have an issue with Firebase Dynamic Link. 
I'm testing with Google Chrome. In case I put the link into an href it works with no problems and the link opens my Android app.
In case I put the link into a JavaScript that redirects the user to the Dynamic Link it does not work: it's like Google Chrome does not find the Android app installed and opens the Google Play instead (that is the default action if the app is not installed).
Does anybody had this same issue?

Comment: Have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610950/firebase-dynamic-link-not-opening-the-app?rq=1).

Comment: I have already checked that question but it hasn't solved my issue

Comment: Assuming your app is on the store, could you add a link or a snippet that reproduces the issue? Easier to debug if we can try it out.